# Botstate.SetConversationData - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: sms, botframework

I am trying to save conversation data via state client and I am getting inconsistent results between the emulator and the sms channels. Testing my bot app via emulator allows me to SetConversationData and GetConversationData fine, but as soon as I try it on sms with service url: https://sms.botframework.com/ I get the following error:

> "exceptionMessage": "Unable to deserialize the response.",
>     "exceptionType": "Microsoft.Rest.SerializationException",
>     "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.SetConversationData(IBotState operations, String channelId, String conversationId, BotData botData)\r\n   at OutboundTestApp.Controllers.OutboundController.Post(OutboundConversationData`1 outboundData)",
>     "innerException": {
>       "message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "exceptionMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
>       "exceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",
>       "stackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String json, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.d__9.MoveNext()"

Here is my code to set the data where the channelId is "sms", conversationId is a valid id and the data is just a simple POCO class:

```
   var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), account);
    stateClient.BotState.SetConversationData(outboundData.ChannelId, conversationResponse.Id, new BotData(data: outboundData.Data));
```

Should I be using SetPrivateConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync and pass in the content type and set my botdata to a json string? I feel the state client is assuming json is being passed somewhere, but the object it is deserializing is actually not json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the serviceUrl was set incorrectly when creating the state client. The baseUri should be https://state.botframework.com.